# How to define resource routes without model name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

With `resources :posts, only: :show { get :detail }` I'll get routes like this.

```
post_detail GET    /posts/:post_id/detail(.:format)                    posts#detail
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                posts#show
```

Can I set route for `post_detail` with `:id` not with `:post_id`?

I know I can set route by `get '/posts/:id/detail', to: 'posts#detail', as: 'post_detail'`, but I want to know if there is a way with `resources`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [add member routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes):

```
resources :posts, only: :show do
  member do
    get 'detail'
  end
end
```

Or without a block:

```
resources :posts, only: :show do
  get 'detail', on: :member
end
```

This creates the following routes:

```
detail_post GET    /posts/:id/detail(.:format)    posts#detail
       post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
```